# Why sigma-finite measure?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, measure-theory

I am learning measure theory and the concept $\sigma$-finite measure makes me a bit confused. Why do we need the $\sigma$-finite assumption in many important theorems?

Comment: See the [Radon-Nikodym Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem)

Comment: @kjetil Thanks for your answer. So the $\sigma$-finite measure assumption is needed because we want to define density functions with respect to this measure. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes. The Radon-Nikodym theorem is very important for statistics, from it comes density functions, likelihood ratios, ...  Besides, it is difficult to imagine situations were $\sigma$-finite measures is not enough.

Answer (score 7):

I want to expand a little more on the answer given in the comments here. First, I think it's useful to give an intuitive explanation as to why it is so powerful. Then, I will discuss some examples where $\sigma$-finiteness is needed.

**Intuition:**

The main intuition is to think of $\sigma$-finite measures spaces as a collection of countably many finite measure spaces being glued together. Thus, when we prove results for $\sigma$-finite spaces we are essentially just finding a way to "string together" the result for these **finite** spaces. This should give you some idea of why it is so powerful since working within a finite measure space is a very strong assumption. Applying this intuition we see that $\sigma$-finite spaces are not really a major generalization away from finite spaces.

**Some Applications:**

To give more insight into this condition I think it is useful to look at some results that can be achieved using $\sigma$-finite measures. The Radon-Nikodym Theorem is certainly one example and indeed it is a cornerstone of probability theory. However, I think there are a few other results that may help to shed some additional light on this condition.

First, from the perspective of probability theory, all non-zero $\sigma$-finite measures are equivalent to probability measures. That is, they agree on sets of measure zero. So there exists a measurable function $g: X\to (0,\infty)$ with $\int g d\mu = 1$ such that,
$$P(A)=\int_A g d\mu$$

You can find a proof of this result [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149273/prove-an-equivalent-criteria-for-sigma-finite-measures). The only modification is to use the function $g := f/\int f d\mu$ to create a probability measure.

Another very important theorem that typically requires $\sigma$-finite measure spaces is [Fubini's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem). Specifically from the perspective of probability theory, this result allows us to work with joint distributions. For example, computing expectations of independent random variables.

Also, a very closely related concept here is the **unique** extension of measures. For non-$\sigma$-finite spaces, we get a failure of Fubini's theorem because the product measures will not extend uniquely without this condition (here is an [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3746785/606804) of this). In fact, notice that the [Caratheodory Extension Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_extension_theorem) requires that the pre-measure be $\sigma$-finite for a unique extension.

A final reason for the importance of $\sigma$-finiteness comes from, perhaps, a slightly deeper result known as the [Lebesgue Decomposition Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_decomposition_theorem). This result tells us that given two $\sigma$-finite measures, $\mu$ and $\nu$, we can write,

$$\nu = \nu_a + \nu_s$$

where $\nu_a << \mu $ (is absolutely continuous w.r.t $\mu$) and $\nu_s \perp \mu$ (singular w.r.t. $\mu$). This theorem can actually be used to write a short proof of the Radon-Nikodym theorem (this is typically called the von Neumann proof).

Finally, we should note that there are [generalizations of $\sigma$-finiteness that do allow us to develop Fubini's theorem and Radon-Nikodym](https://mathoverflow.net/a/258998/174500). Still, we need some generalization of this condition. Furthermore, the equivalence of $\sigma$-finite measures to probability measures certainly is a strong motivation for using $\sigma$-finitenes when we develop these results in probability theory.

Comment: I like your comment on how all non-zero $\sigma$-finite measures are equivalent to probability measures; I see this as the most important reason we care about $\sigma$-finite measures.

Comment: @David Veitch Absolutely! From the perspective of statistics it makes it a very natural choice.